# Filter non-posting Invoices in Quickbooks Connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, invoices

I have this xml:

```
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="${requestID}">
        <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
            <FromModifiedDate >${from}</FromModifiedDate> 
            <ToModifiedDate >${to}</ToModifiedDate>
        </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
        <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
    </InvoiceQueryRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
```

I want filter invoices to get only non-posting invoices. I search in the https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html but not found like filter invoices by non-posting attibute.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How you solved it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickBooks SDK does not offer a way to filter by only posting invoices.

You'll have to query for all of them, and then filter them within your application based on the `<IsPending>` XML tag that is returned.